# Adding tabs between two parts of one equation

Tags: spacing, equations

I need to add a tab between after the semicolon in the equation shown below:

```
\begin{equation}
Thr =  4\sigma_n;\sigma_n = median \left(\frac{|x|}{0.6745}\right)
\end{equation}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: `\quad` or `\qquad`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the comments: you can use the `subequations` environment from the `amsmath` package and some of the display math environments also provided by this package; the following example shows two options using `align` (aligned expressions) and `gather` (no alignment); to get the dot between the equation and its "parent", one can redefine `\theequation`, as shown in the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations} 
\renewcommand\theequation{\theparentequation.\alph{equation}}
\begin{align} 
\text{Thr} &= 4\sigma_n;  \\
\sigma_n &= \text{median} \left(\frac{|x|}{0.6745}\right) 
\end{align}
\end{subequations} 

\begin{subequations} 
\renewcommand\theequation{\theparentequation.\alph{equation}}
\begin{gather} 
\text{Thr} = 4\sigma_n;  \\
\sigma_n = \text{median} \left(\frac{|x|}{0.6745}\right) 
\end{gather}
\end{subequations} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also the use of `\text` (from the `amsmath` package) to obtain upright text font for "Thr" and "median".

Comment: I need to make the part before the semicolon as part(a) and in the next line the other part and called part (b)

Comment: @sherifHaggag - Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by `part (a)` and `part (b)`? Do you mean that "part (a)" and "part (b)" should be written below the two sub-expressions?

Comment: I need the shape to be like this:
Thr = 4σn;    (1.a)
σn = median   (1.b)

Comment: @sherifHaggag please see my updated answer.